# A probability distribution problem

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

Is this a negative binomial distribution? How to solve this particular problem?

Two ball players, denoted **A** and **B**, are practicing their scoring skill in their respective sports. The probability that **A** will score in any attempt is $p$, and **A** tries until they have scored $r$ times. The probability that **B** will score in any attempt is $mp$, where $m$ is a given integer $(m = 2, 3, . . .)$ such that $mp < 1$, and **B** tries until they have scored $mr$ times.

(a) For which player (**A** or **B**) is the expected number of failed attempts smaller? Solved.

(b) For which player is the variance of the total number of attempts smaller?

Comment: Yes it is a negative binomial distribution.  So you need to calculate the two means and variances and then compare.

Comment: Yes, you are dealing with [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Definition). Only be aware that scoring is looked at as failure. Quite unnatural of course.

Comment: I got that mean of A is larger than mean of B, but var of A smaller than var of B. Is that correct? @drhab

Comment: Check it with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A,B$ denote the number of failed attempts of **A** and **B** respectively.

We can write $A=A_1+\cdots +A_r$ where the $A_i$ are iid and $A_1$ has [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with parameter $p$ and stands for the number of failures before a first score is made by **A**.

Likewise we can write $B=B_1+\cdots +B_{mr}$ this time dealing with parameter $pm$.

Then $\mathbb EA_1=\frac1p-1$ and $\text{Var}A_1=\frac{1}{p^2}-\frac1p$.

For $B_1$ likewise with parameter $pm$.

Expectation of $A$ and $B$ are now easy to find by linearity of expectation.

Also variance is easy to find since the variance of a summation of independent random variables equals the summation of variances.

Comment: How to find expectations from that?

Comment: As I said: use linearity of expectation. $\mathbb EA=\mathbb EA_1+\cdots+\mathbb EA_r$.

Comment: Thanks. So what is the $\mathbb EA_2$? How to use linearity of expectation here

Comment: As said in the answer $A_1, A_2,\dots$ are iid (independent identically distributed) so $\mathbb EA_2=\mathbb EA_1$. How to use it? See my former comment. To make things more clear: if **A** scores for the first time on $5$th try and for the second on $8$th try then $A_1$ takes value $4$ and $A_2$ takes value $2$. You will simply get $\mathbb EA=r\mathbb EA_1=r(\frac1p-1)$.